# Interleaving the rows of a numpy matrix, generate permuation scheme

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix, which I want to shuffle row-wise according to the following scheme described below:

We have our matrix `a`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
low = -5
high = 5

num_frames = 2
other_value = 3
dim1 = num_frames * other_value
dim2 = 5
a_shape = (dim1, dim2)
a = np.random.random_integers(low, high, size=a_shape)
print(a)

[[ 0 -5 -2 -2  2]
 [ 4 -2  0 -3 -1]
 [ 2  1  3  3  5]
 [-4  1  2  2  3]
 [-4  0  4  3  4]
 [-1 -2 -5 -2  0]]
```

And we want to split our rows into `num_frames` groups.  So for our matrix `a`, with 2 frames, our split would look like this:

```
[[ 0 -5 -2 -2  2]
 [ 4 -2  0 -3 -1]
 [ 2  1  3  3  5]

 [-4  1  2  2  3]
 [-4  0  4  3  4]
 [-1 -2 -5 -2  0]]
```

We then want to interleave the rows of each frame, so the permutation would be given as `[0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]`, where these numbers are row indices.

For `a`, that would give us a matrix that looks like this:

```
[[ 0 -5 -2 -2  2]
[-4  1  2  2  3]
[ 4 -2  0 -3 -1]
[-4  0  4  3  4]
[ 2  1  3  3  5]
[-1 -2 -5 -2  0]]
```

If we had 3 frames, but the same number of rows (so `other_value=2`), our permutation would be `[0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]`, giving a matrix:

```
 [[ 0 -5 -2 -2  2]
 [ 2  1  3  3  5]
 [-4  0  4  3  4]
 [ 4 -2  0 -3 -1]     
 [-4  1  2  2  3]
 [-1 -2 -5 -2  0]]
```

The thing I can't quite grok is:

What sort of ways might one generate the correct permutation for arbitrary sized matrices, and number of frames?  The assumption is that we will always have the same number of rows in each frame (or, `dim1 % num_frames = 0`).

A way to permute the rows would be the below code, but I'm not sure how to get the permutation.

```
b = a.copy()
perm = [0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
b[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] = a[perm]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one function to do what you want using `np.reshape` and `np.transpose`:

```
def interleave_frames(a, num_frames):
    if len(a) % num_frames != 0: raise ValueError
    frame_size = len(a) // num_frames
    out = np.reshape(a, (num_frames, frame_size, -1))
    out = np.transpose(out, (1, 0, 2))
    return np.reshape(out, (len(a), -1))
```

Test:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
low = -5
high = 5
num_frames = 2
other_value = 3
dim1 = num_frames * other_value
dim2 = 5
a_shape = (dim1, dim2)
a = np.random.random_integers(low, high, size=a_shape)
print('Array:')
print(a)
print('Interleaved:')
print(interleave_frames(a, num_frames))
```

Output:

```
Array:
[[ 0 -5 -2 -2  2]
 [ 4 -2  0 -3 -1]
 [ 2  1  3  3  5]
 [-4  1  2  2  3]
 [-4  0  4  3  4]
 [-1 -2 -5 -2  0]]
Interleaved:
[[ 0 -5 -2 -2  2]
 [-4  1  2  2  3]
 [ 4 -2  0 -3 -1]
 [-4  0  4  3  4]
 [ 2  1  3  3  5]
 [-1 -2 -5 -2  0]]
```

EDIT:

If you actually want to obtain the indices anyway, the same approach (reshape/transpose/reshape) is applicable:

```
print(np.arange(len(a)).reshape((num_frames, -1)).transpose().reshape(-1))
# [0 3 1 4 2 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop logic should give the desired permutations:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

num_frames = 2
other_value = 3

new_list = []
for i in range(other_value):
    for j in range(i, len(a), other_value):
        new_list.append(j)

print new_list
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your permutation, you could do:

```
def perm(nb_rows, nb_frames):
    return [frame*nb_rows//nb_frames + row for row in range(nb_rows // nb_frames)      
                                           for frame in range(nb_frames)]

print(perm(6, 2))
# [0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]

print(perm(6, 3))
# [0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]

print(perm(20, 4))
# [0, 5, 10, 15, 1, 6, 11, 16, 2, 7, 12, 17, 3, 8, 13, 18, 4, 9, 14, 19]
```